# How to build google test and google mock lib and use them in VS console app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

How to create a google test based unit testing project that integrate latest gtest.lib and gmock.lib in a console application or empty project (don't want to use visual studio google test project template)

Tried using google test project template in visual studio. Downloaded source zip of google test from github.

Comment: did you read the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/quickstart-cmake.md)?

Comment: yes, was able to build x64 release libs only with the cmakelist present in source.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Download the  google test source zip and unzip.

2 . Use command

```
cmake . -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON
```

Then

```
cmake --build .
```

It will generate the debug version libs with /MDd.

3 . Create a console app in Visual Studio.

Add header file **folder directory** in project's properties -> C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

Add lib **folder directory** in project's properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories.

Input used library name in Linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies.
Such as

```
gtest.lib
gtest_main.lib
```

Remove `int main(){}`.
Add sample:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

Comment: Hi,  @Shashank
May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?